# Can anyone correct my Ruby routes.rb syntax error please?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, routes

I am experimenting with the twitter-bootstrap nav-bar and I am having issues with the last step on this tutorial:http://johnnysky.com/tag/twitter-bootstrap.

I tried his exact code and got errors so I started messing with it trying to fix it and this is what I have so far in my routes.rb:

```
  match '/search', to: =>'pages#search', via: 'get'

  match '/faq', to: =>'pages#faq', via: 'get'

  match '/my_account', to: =>'pages#my_account', via: 'get'

  match '/how_it_works', to: =>'pages#how_it_works', via: 'get'

  match '/contact_us', to: =>'pages#contact_us', via: 'get'
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
   C:/CoOp/config/routes.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ',', e
xpecting keyword_end
  match '/faq', to: =>'pages#faq', via: 'get'
                                  ^
C:/HandCoOp/project/HandCoOp/config/routes.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected =>
  match '/my_account', to: =>'pages#my_account', via: 'get'
                             ^
C:/HandCoOp/project/HandCoOp/config/routes.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ',', e
xpecting keyword_end
  match '/my_account', to: =>'pages#my_account', via: 'get'
                                                ^
C:/HandCoOp/project/HandCoOp/config/routes.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected =>
  match '/how_it_works', to: =>'pages#how_it_works', via: 'get'
                               ^
C:/HandCoOp/project/HandCoOp/config/routes.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected ',',
expecting keyword_end
  match '/how_it_works', to: =>'pages#how_it_works', via: 'get'
                                                    ^
C:/HandCoOp/project/HandCoOp/config/routes.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected =>
  match '/contact_us', to: =>'pages#contact_us', via: 'get'
                             ^
C:/HandCoOp/project/HandCoOp/config/routes.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ',',
expecting keyword_end
  match '/contact_us', to: =>'pages#contact_us', via: 'get'
                                                ^
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?  Thanks for taking a look and I will keep looking for solutions.  Cheers!

```
 match '/search', to: 'pages#search', via: 'get'

  match '/faq', to: 'pages#faq', via: 'get'

  match '/my_account', to: 'pages#my_account', via: 'get'

  match '/how_it_works', to: 'pages#how_it_works', via: 'get'

  match '/contact_us', to: 'pages#contact_us', via: 'get'
```

Comment: ^^^^^This was my correct routes.rb, Thanks Frederick Cheung! :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashes in ruby either use the json-esque style

```
{key: value}
```

Or the traditional hashrocket

```
{key => value}
```

But you are using some amalgam of both syntaxes

```
to: => value
```

Which is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, I will remove the arrows, I found them on a different stack question.  I will post any more errors I get after the "Cheers!" above.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you for helping me fix my syntax and I hope I can do the same someday.